# Excel VBA set row height for inserted row

Tags: excel, vba

I just figured out how to insert rows below cell with value. However as an addition I would like inserted row to be specific height, lets say for example 7. This code is a part of large code so I don't save `sub` in my example.

The problem is that this code is not working for setting RowHeight. First part is is inserting new row but there is no effect on Height of the rows.

I have tried the following one:

```
Dim rng as Range

        For Each Rng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offer Letter").Range("E2:E60")
        If Not IsEmpty(Rng) Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next


        For Each Rng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offer Letter").Range("E2:E60")
        If Not IsEmpty(Rng) Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.RowHeight = 7
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what your problem is, but you don't need two loops. Set the height when you insert the row.

Thanks to @JvdV for pointing out that when deleting or inserting rows one should loop backwards to avoid missing/skipping rows.

```
Sub y()

Dim r As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offer Letter")
    For r = 60 To 2 Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(r, "E")) Then
            .Cells(r + 1, "E").EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(r + 1, "E").EntireRow.RowHeight = 7
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This one also inserting rows where needed, but does not set RowHeight for some reason.

Comment: It works for me. Try changing all the row heights before running the code.

Comment: You are risking missing some cells when using this loop, adding rows below current rng. Rather go backwards in a loop eliminating the chance of missing some rows.